# TypeError: filtredItems.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

please any help!

I create a simple code to filter items based on an input value but I got an ERROR :( even though am sure I did everything correctly following the same steps in the tutorial https://youtu.be/cahFm8eeeJI?list=PL6bwFJ82M6FXjyBTVi6WSCWin8q_g_8RR&t=1160

This is the Whole code pages/index.js

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'

const List = ({items}) => {

  const [filtredItems, setFiltredItems] = useState(items)

  const filterItems = (e) => {
    const searchValue = e.target.value
    const currentItems = [...items]
    const matchingItems = currentItems.filter((item)=> item.includes(searchValue))

    setFiltredItems(matchingItems)
  }

  return (
    <>
      <input onChanged={filterItems}/>
      <ul>
        {/* <li>React JS</li>
        <li>Next JS</li>
        <li>Javascript</li> */}
        {filtredItems.map((item)=>(
          <li key={item}>{item}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </>
  )
}

const ListContainer = () => {
  return (
    <List items={'ReactJS', 'NextJS', 'Javascript'}/>
  )
}

export default ListContainer
```

output>>>>

**TypeError: filtredItems.map is not a function**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Va8Cy.png)

Thank you.

Comment: This is the time you start using any Prop validation technique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`items={'ReactJS', 'NextJS', 'Javascript'}` should be `items={['ReactJS', 'NextJS', 'Javascript']}` so you're passing an array. Without the `[]`, you're just using the comma operator to pass the string `"Javascript"` as `items`.

---

Separately, though, it's problematic to copy props into state the way you are in that component. If the parent passes *new* items to the child component, it won't see them until/unless the user filters again, because `items` is only used as the initial value of `filtredItems` (sic).

Instead, keep track of the search value and do the filtering when either `items` or `searchValue` changes:

```
const List = ({ items }) => {
    // Remember the search value
    const [searchValue, setSearchValue] = useState(null);
    // Remember the current filtered items (null = not filtering)
    const [filteredItems, setFilteredItems] = useState(null);

    // Filter the items by search filter when either `items` or `searchValue` changes
    useEffect(() => {
        const matchingItems = searchValue
            ? items.filter((item) => item.includes(searchValue))
            : items;
        setFilteredItems(matchingItems);
    }, [items, searchValue]);

    const filterItems = (e) => {
        setSearchValue(e.target.value.trim());
    };

    return (
        <>
            <input onChange={filterItems} value={searchValue} />
            <ul>
                {
                    (filteredItems ?? items).map((item) => (
                        <li key={item}> {item} </li>
                    ))
                }
            </ul>
        </>
    );
};
```

*(I also fixed a couple of typos in there, such as `filtredItems` => `filteredItems` and `onChanged` => `onChange`.)*

Comment: Thank you so much for refactoring the code. Yes i got again a new error of the property onChanged. then looking at your code i discover that i made another mistake. Thank you again for your help Sir T.J. Crowder. May i Ask you about the concept of children and parent component because they confuse me a lot. for example if i want to create a Layout.js in my nextjs project i will create it like this: const Layout = ({children}) => {} .. then in _app.js we pass the Layout Component which one is the children !! and which one is the parent :(((  Thank you again. i really appreciate your help

Comment: @Aykc - Glad that helped. The parent component is the one that contains the child. So for instance, `function Parent() { return <Child />; }`. Happy coding!

Comment: please who is the parent and the child component here in your code ?

Comment: @Aykc - `List` is the child, and whatever is using it (`ListContainer`, it looks like) is the parent.

Comment: Yes Sir, I do understand. Thank you so much for the time you gave to help me. Thank you again and again. i am really struggling learning react but i will not give up